# What is the implicit operation for power sets in the context of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Below is the question asked by Pinter in A Book of Abstract Algebra, Chapter 14 Exercise A6.

[image: Chapter 14 Exercise A6]

I am totally fine with the first part of the question (where we complete the element by element mapping for $h$).

It's the second part, where the reader is asked to show that

> $h$ is a homomorphism for any $A$ and $B \backepsilon B \subset A$

that has me a little confused. **Is there some implicit operation that is being referenced for power sets?** *(and when talking about power sets in the context of groups...is this implicit operation the only one?*) Further, I am guessing that the operation in $P_A$ is the same operation that is used in $P_B$? Any clarity would be appreciated!

Comment: It probably means [set algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets) homomorphism, $A$ is not even a group.

Comment: @Conifold Oh...really? I interpreted it as the power set $P_A$ being the group...and $A$ is simply one of the elements of $P_A$. As such, I need an operation. For the moment, I assumed it was the operation of symmetric difference...but I did not know for sure.

Comment: Well, the powerset is a Boolean ring with symmetric difference for addition and intersection for multiplication, so that would imply it. It's hard to say what Pinter means without looking at the book.